# adding a video to home page banner

Tags: magento2.2, blocks, home-page, video

I am trying to add a video on banner of my home page but the video doesn't appear, it shows a message no video with supported format. I uploaded a mp4 format and mov format but it shows the same message .. I added the video with a block on home page. what should I do to get it to work properly

Comment: to work properly*

Comment: Is working or not?

Comment: Please describes in details.

Answer (score 1):

create a block in magento admin use below code.

```
<video id="myVideo" width="100%" height="300px" autoplay="autoplay" muted="" loop="loop">
<source src="{{view url="images/banner.mp4"}}" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey You can use  to upload video anywhere in your magento site

Use below Code:

```
<iframe width="500" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fzb-qLL2wo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```